# iphone app paradigm

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller

I'm developing an app and was looking for some help on one of the concepts. Im not sure the best way to achieve it so here it goes. Basically throughout the app I need an option on every screen to access a settings view (not full screen, but pop over). This settings screen allows users to navigate to new viewControllers etc. My issue is Im not sure of the correct design model. Should I have a viewController for the settings view or just have all separate viewControllers have their own settings view and manage them themselves? Should I use delegation for the settings viewController? If anyone has a good concept of how to achieve this I'd love to hear it. Many thanks.

Jules

Comment: ok Just accepted a couple more but in all honesty I do accept when I feel my question has been answered.

Comment: thanks for the effort. I understand sometimes you don't get any valid answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do it is to create the settingsViewController in the appDelegate class. And call it from anywhere through NSNotification. This way you handle the code in one place and are able to get it to open from anywhere.

Comment: This sounds reasonable, but could you clarify thw need for the notification? Would it not be feasible to just have IBActions in the viewControllers and then load according to these? Many thanks

Comment: You would have IBAction that would react to a button press. In that method you would send an nsnotification. That notification is received by your appDelegate and opens settings for you. In stead of nsnotification you can also call a method of your appDelegate directly. But I feel it's cleaner to use notifications when creating settings accessible from different parts of the app. It's your choice.

Comment: I see.... perhaps its my fault for saying "settings" It really is a view with options to do many things including navigate to other pages. So I would have to push things onto the navStack... Is this still feasible using this design pattern in your opinion? Many thanks again